# Will ice be cold or not when formed using pressure?

Tags: temperature, intermolecular-forces, solid-state-chemistry, pressure

We know that ice can be formed either by lowering the temperature of water or by applying more pressure. If we lower the temperature of water the ice so formed will be cool which is obvious.

If ice is created by applying pressure, will it be cold as well?

Comment: Being cold and having a cooling effect are two different things.

Comment: Who downvoted without comment? Doesn't help the poster...

Answer (score 3):

Water can be formed by applied pressure, but only at certain temperatures. Looking at the phase diagram below, you can see that water must be at 0 C until extreme pressures are reached. This can create ice, but it would only remain solid under these pressure conditions at that temperature. The ice would have a cooling effect on surroundings that have a higher temperature, in fact the rapid change back to liquid would cool the surroundings, but the ice would not be cold. This ice would also quickly revert to another phase if not held under these pressure conditions.

So, if at the bottom of a deep, high gravity sea, the ice will form at temp above 0C. If it starts floating upward, the lower pressure will allow it to melt.

If you create warm ice in a hydraulic ram, it will melt as soon as pressure is relieved.

[image: Triple point of Water]